# Why is app crashing when showing UIAlertView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uialertview

I've implemented the Reachability function in a method that handles all the server requests. I can see through NSLogs that the function works perfectly. However there is never a "pause" within the method which means I can't use the UIAlertView without crashing the program.

I might be going at this the completely wrong way, but I can't find anything else...

Does anybody have an idea of how to get a notification to show somehow?

Thanks in advance

CODE:

```
-(id) getJson:(NSString *)stringurl{
Reachability * reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];

NSLog(@"reached %d", reach.isReachable);

if (reach.isReachable == NO) {

   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Passwords don't match."
     message:@"The passwords did not match. Please try again."
     delegate:nil
     cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
     otherButtonTitles:nil];
     [alert show];

}else{
    id x =[self getJsonFromHttp:stringurl];
    return x;
}
return nil;
}
```

Comment: Could you at least post the entirety of the 'function' to which the title refers to? Would like to see more code -- and perhaps a clearer description.

Comment: Done. Although I don't think it will help too much with the extra part... The idea is to somehow make me able to show the UIAlertView without the program crashing. Is there a way to "pause" the app until the alert box have been dismissed? Or should I have a completely different approach to the problem?

Comment: Does your code even compile with that empty return; statement after [alert show]? Should return something since the compiler is looking for you to return an (id).

Comment: My bad. Leftovers from some experimenting... Removed now!

Comment: And about your "Pause" question -- I'm not sure what the rest of your code does but if you have some asynchronous requests happening in the background it will be a headache to try to manage a Pause for the main and background threads. I suggest trying to narrow down the cause of the crash by (1) identifying all elements that might be involved and then (2) doing some kind of NSLog test on each element to rule out anything thats not. You'll be surprised at how quick you'll arrive at the culprit in this way.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions for how to show the alertview? Or is that even the appropriate way to notify the user?
Any ideas that might bring me closer to a solution are freatly appreciated

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22074/discussion-between-eric-and-user1534948)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After moving the discussion to a chat, we discovered that your UIAlertView was being called from a background thread. Never do anything related to updating the UI (*User-Interface*) in a background thread. The UIAlertView updates the UI by adding a little pop-up dialog, so it should be done on the main thread. Fix by making these changes:

```
// (1) Create a new method in your .m/.h and move your UIAlertView code to it
-(void)showMyAlert{ 

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Passwords don't match." 
                           message:@"The passwords did not match. Please try again." 
                           delegate:nil 
                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                           otherButtonTitles:nil]; 
    [alert show]; 

}

// (2) In -(id)getJson replace your original UI-related code with a call to your new method
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showMyAlert)
                             withObject:nil
                          waitUntilDone:YES];
```